# Data Access Layer with Enterprise Library in Mobile Applications

Tags: enterprise-library, sql-server-ce, data-access-layer

How can I use Enterprise Library to do a Data Access Layer in c# for Sql CE and .NET Compact Framework?

I haven't found clear examples. I would like to learn Enterprise Library but any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Enterprise Library with Compact Framework, it's only available for dekstop/server.